# Normalize Data in Google Sheets - TRANSPOSE multiple columns Fill Down

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have data I need normalized.  Any value in Col C separated by a comma needs its own row.

Here is my [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PD9B8kE0phf7Te8qaUS0EmNAJxhyDD72wo4o_Qk3WJM/edit#gid=1756397733)

The Data is in Col A - Col C and the Desired Result is int Col E-ColG.

This question was helpful and I got the formula working for col C but when I try to integrate col A and B it breaks:

[Transpose, Split, and Join Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52253353/transpose-split-and-join-google-sheets)

Comment: Can you give view or edit access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a scalable modification of [@ttarchala's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34704/) solution:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(
 "♦", 1, $A3:A&"♠"&$B3:B&"♠"&IFERROR(SPLIT(C3:C, ", ")))), "♦")), "♠"),
 "where Col2<>'' and Col3<>''"))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(IFERROR(TEXTJOIN( "♦", 1, 
 SUBSTITUTE($A3:A&"♠"&$B3:B&"♠"&IFERROR(SPLIT(
 REGEXREPLACE(C3:C, ", |,", "♥"), "♥")), "♠♠", ""))), "♦")), "♠"), "where Col3<>''"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks.  It breaks when I added more data.  It looks like this is best formula (KPV Test Tab): =ArrayFormula(Query(TRIM(split(transpose(split(textjoin("|",1,if(len(C3:C),REGEXREPLACE(C3:C&",",",","|"&A3:A&"|"&B3:B&","),)),",")),"|")),"Select Col2,Col3,Col1"))

Comment: well, you kinda broke the pattern with adding different stuff (non-comma list and items with space). answer updated and formula fixed

Comment: this is great, thanks.  sorry about that.  I should have added more variations to begin with.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

In case anyone else was confused by the "♥" & "♦" - they're meant to be characters which are very unlikely to be found in a normal spreadsheet.

@player0 suggestion works well, but in my work it would error out after 140 rows (50 rows in the spreadsheet above).

moonshot's KPV (KPV?) formula works with more rows, and also has bonus removal of whitespace after comma with REGEXREPLACE and TRIM.

Good work.

Answer (score 2):

This rather long formula will do what you want

```
=query(
  arrayformula(
    split(
      transpose(
        split(
          textjoin(
            "\",
            0,
            $B3:B4 &
              "|" & 
              split(C3:C4, ", ")
          ),
          "\"
        )
      ),
      "|"
    )
  ),
  "select * where Col2 <> ''"
)
```

[image]

Explanation: really too long and too boring to write. Just rebuild the query starting from the innermost formulas to see how it works.

Adding the column A is left as an exercise to the reader.